# jquery addclass then use as selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find out how to use a class that I add as a selector in jquery after I add the class. So essentially when I change a daterange with the ID #ds_i it adds a class to a button and when that button is pressed I will get a pop up. The code I have so far is as follows.

```
    $("#ds_i").on('change', function(){  
        $( "#save-button" ).addClass( "sweet-date-pop" );
    });

    $(".sweet-date-pop").click(function(e,params) {
    var localParams = params || {};

    if (!localParams.send) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    swal({
        title: "This job is in progress.",
        text: "Are you sure you would like to change the dates?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-warning",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes,change dates!",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false
    }, function(isConfirm){
        if (isConfirm) {
            $(e.currentTarget).trigger(e.type, {'send': true});
        } else {
            swal("Cancelled", "Nothing Was Changed", "error");
        }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate it from body

```
$("body").on('click','.sweet-date-pop',function(e,params) {
 //rest of the code
})
```

Comment: Quick off the mark! And, of course, correct.